# Stacking neural nets with cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, ensemble-learning

I am trying to implement stacking model for a ML problem and having hard time figuring out the cross validation strategy. So far I have used 10-fold cross validation for all my models and would like continue using that stacking as well. Here's what I came up with but not sure if it makes sense,

1. At each iteration of 10-fold CV, you will have 9 folds for training (training dataset) and 1 fold for testing (testing dataset).
2. Divide the training dataset into 3 parts - F1, F2 and F3.
3. Train base classifiers on F1, use F2 for early stopping and get out of fold predictions  on F3 -> F3'
4. Train base classifiers on F2, use F3 for early stopping and get out of fold predictions  on F1 -> F1'
5. Train base classifiers on F3, use F1 for early stopping and get out of fold predictions  on F2 -> F2'
6. Train meta-classifier on (F1' + F2' + F3'), train base-classifiers on any two folds and  use remaining fold for early-stopping.
7. Validate meta-classifier on test dataset

Repeat these steps for every fold in 10 fold CV.

Comment: What are those F1', F2', F3' ? Could you describe the stacking part of your approach a little more?

Comment: F1', F2', F3' are predictions made by base-classifiers on F1,F2, F3 respectively. I will edit the post to make it more clear.